# How to get value of selected option in a dropdown using React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get the selected value of the dropdown using React Js.

It is giving the values but is giving the values randomly from the the options.

```
<select 
    name="category-select-1"
    class="form-select category-select" 
    id="category-select-1" 
    value={eventCategory} 
    onChange={handleEventCategory}>
    <option value={"default"}>Category</option>
    <option value={"meeting"}>Meeting</option>
    <option value={"workhours"}>Work Hours</option>
    <option value={"business"}>Business</option>
    <option value={"holiday"}>Holiday</option>
    <option value={"getTogether"}>Get-Together</option>
    <option value={"gifts"}>Gifts</option>
    <option value={"birthday"}>Birthday</option>
    <option value={"anniversary"}>Anniversary</option>
    <option value={"others"}>Others</option>
</select>
```

Here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
const [eventCategory, setEventCategory] = useState();

const handleEventCategory = (e)=>{
    setEventCategory(e.target.value);
    console.log(eventCategory);
}
```

What is wrong?

How do I get the value of a selected option in a dropdown using React JS?

Comment: you can check that by putting the log `console.log(eventCategory);` outside of the handler function .... as the state updates are more of like async i.e., with state update it re-renders which is the function body gets called with new values

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(eventCategory)
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [eventCategory])
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "eventCategory" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

Comment: I don't think an useEffect is required here ...

Comment: Yes, it's not really required here since he currently only logs the value to console, but if he were to need that value then he could indeed use the `useEffect` hook to allow for that. The main point I was trying to convey, however, is the "async-like" behavior of `setState`.

Comment: got it buddy, however my point was to convey the same without confusing with an extra info 

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.

```
const handleEventCategory = (e)=>{
    setEventCategory(e.target.value);
    console.log(eventCategory);
}

console.log(eventCategory);
```

As setState is asynchronous, eventCategory value is printed before the state is changed. If you add console.log below the handleEventCategory you will get right output.